# Ferrite core through PCB, how to close?

Tags: pcb, ferrite, glue

While opening what is labelled as a "Badge Isolator" from a dishwasher, a Ferrite core broke.

The core goes through the PCB, and is comprised of a U part and an I part.

I am going to assume that the I was glued on the U, after mounting them on the PCB.

So the I part came off, and the U part broke in two pieces.
I thought I would just super-glue everything together and be done.

However, the dishwasher no longer works.

Is a Ferrite Core that susceptible to cracks?
How did the manufacturer close the core loop? Using a special purpose glue? Or would any glue work?

[image: Ferrite Core going through a PCB, glued.]

Comment: Such ferrite cores are available as replacement parts. Take measures and buy one fitting through the holes you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That ferrite core is being used as the core for a transformer (note the swirly traces). Your adhesive has introduced a very small gap in the core, which will alter its performance and could be the cause of it not working anymore.

Here's some interesting reading on gluing ferrite cores for transformers (they try to go for a 5um to 50um gap in the core introduced by the adhesive): http://elnamagnetics.com/wp-content/uploads/library/elna-magnetics/gluing_of_ferrite_cores.pdf

Comment: Thanks. So yeah, I'm assuming then that from-factory, the core had two glue points, and after my fix, it now has three glue points. But maybe my gluing was a lot less precise than what the factory did.